# wrong arguments were passed to displayImage method in universal-Image

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I used this library lots of time. But I get an exception from Eclipse that the title name. Codes are here;

```
public class HaberDetay extends Activity {

private HaberlerItems haberitem = null;
private ImageLoader imageloader;
private ImageView haberImage;
private TextView lblTitle, lblDescription, lblTarih;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_haber_detay);

    imageloader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            getApplicationContext()).build();
    imageloader.init(config);

    lblTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblTitle);
    lblDescription = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblDescription);
    lblTarih = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblTarih);
    haberImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgHaber);

    haberitem = (HaberlerItems)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("haberitem");

    if(haberitem != null){
        lblTarih.setText(haberitem.getDateAdded());
        lblTitle.setText(haberitem.getTitle());
        lblDescription.setText(Html.fromHtml(haberitem.getDescription()));
        imageloader.displayImage(haberitem.getImageUrl(), haberImage);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.haber_detay, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

you know displayImage is a method of this class. I cant see any error or exception. What can i do?

Comment: Are you update your sdk tool to 22 ?

Comment: I used the same as another class wiyhout exception and error. So sdk is not important

Answer (score 0):

Parameters to `displayImage` is location, view and options

```
 imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], imageView, options);
```

look into the sample

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/sample/src/com/nostra13/example/universalimageloader/ImageGalleryActivity.java

Comment: Also there imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], imageView);  this method. only url and imageView.

Comment: mageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            getApplicationContext()).build();   I used here getApplicationContext() instead of context. This is not an error isn't it?